# Images Flickering on Pygame

Tags: image, pygame

I am trying to add some buttons to my program and I have managed to put them on there. However, they keep flickering and I'm not sure how to stop that problem. The sizes and positioning are going to be changed later I just used random positions for now so ignore that. I put pygame.display.flip() everywhere hoping that would fix it. However, it did not. Thank you

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
from pygame.rect import Rect

PINK = (250, 100, 100)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

#initialize pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

#images
loginBut = pygame.image.load('loginBut.png').convert_alpha()
signupBut = pygame.image.load('signupBut.png').convert_alpha()

pygame.display.flip()

#variables
xbut = 300
ybut1 = 350
ybut2 = 450

def create_surface_with_text(text, font_size, text_rgb, bg_rgb):
    font = pygame.freetype.SysFont("Arial", font_size, bold=True)
    surface, _ = font.render(text=text, fgcolor=text_rgb, bgcolor=bg_rgb)
    return surface.convert_alpha()

def loginButton(xbut,ybut1):
    screen.blit(loginBut,(xbut,ybut1))
    pygame.display.update()

def signupButton(xbut,ybut2):
    screen.blit(signupBut,(xbut,ybut2))
    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.display.flip()

class UIElement(Sprite):
   
    def __init__(self, center_position, text, font_size, bg_rgb, text_rgb):
     
        self.mouse_over = False  

        # what happens when the mouse is not over the element
        default_image = create_surface_with_text(
            text=text, font_size=font_size, text_rgb=text_rgb, bg_rgb=bg_rgb
        )

        # what happens when the mouse is over the element
        highlighted_image = create_surface_with_text(
            text=text, font_size=font_size * 1.1, text_rgb=text_rgb, bg_rgb=bg_rgb
        )

        self.images = [default_image, highlighted_image]
        self.rects = [
            default_image.get_rect(center=center_position),
            highlighted_image.get_rect(center=center_position),
        ]

        super().__init__()

    @property
    def image(self):
        return self.images[1] if self.mouse_over else self.images[0]

    @property
    def rect(self):
        return self.rects[1] if self.mouse_over else self.rects[0]

    def update(self, mouse_pos):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.mouse_over = True
        else:
            self.mouse_over = False

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

        pygame.display.flip()


def main():
    pygame.init()
    
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

    uielement = UIElement(
        center_position=(400, 100),
        font_size=40,
        bg_rgb=PINK,
        text_rgb=BLACK,
        text="Welcome to the Automated Timetable Program",
    )

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(PINK)

        uielement.update(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        uielement.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        loginButton(xbut,ybut1)
        signupButton(xbut,ybut2)
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the multiple calles of `pygame.display.flip()`. Multiple calls to `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` cause flickering. Remove all the calls of `pygame.display.flip()` from the code, but call it once at the end of the application loop.